# ¿Por qué la suma me sigue dando cero?

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de escribir una función la cual toma los elementos de un **array** y devuelve una **suma** de todos los elementos que **no esten repetidos**.

```
function repeats(arr){
  var num;
  var sum = 0;
  var repeat = false;
  
  for(var i=0; i < arr.lenght; i++)
  {
    repeat = false;
    
    for(var j =i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
    {
      if(arr[j] === arr[i])
      {
        repeat = true;
      }
    };
    
    if(repeat)
      continue; 
   
      num = arr[i];
      sum += num;
  };
  return sum;
};
```

Un bucle `i` itera cada elemento del array, donde luego un segundo bucle `j` itera todos los elementos **despues** del elemento actual del primer bucle, si el bucle `j` encuentra un elemento igual al actual; una bandera `repeat` avisará para hacer la siguiente iteración sin realizar la suma.

El problema es que al momento de retornar `sum` esta sigue valiendo cero.

Estuve probando cambiar el orden en el que ocurre cada ejecución pero sin importar que, `sum` no parece cambiar de valor durante toda la función.

Comment: elimina el  ```continue; ``` dentro del if, puede que se salte la suma de elementos y haga la siguiente iteracion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay un error de escritura en el primer for `arr.lenght` debe ser `arr.length`

```js
function repeats(arr) {
    var num;
    var sum = 0;
    var repeat = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        repeat = false;

        for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] === arr[i]) {
                repeat = true;
            }
        };

        if (repeat)
            continue;

        num = arr[i];
        sum += num;
    };
    return sum;
};

console.log(repeats([1, 1, 1, 1, 2]));
```

Comment: Sin comentarios... supongo que a la proxima me aseguro de leer letra por letra